# How to interpolate a paramenter in a django template?

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I have the folowing fragment of code in a django-temlplate:

```
<svg class="wave α-wave">
    {% for i in '0000000000000'|make_list %}
        <rect width="3rem" height="0.5rem" x="{{ forloop.counter0 }} * 3rem"></rect>
    {% endfor %}
</svg>
```

When compilated, x parameter is calculated to 0 for each `<rect>`. I expect it to be `forloop.counter0 * 3` rem

Comment: Because `3rem` is not a numeric value, that you could actually perform a multiplication with? You will need to multiple your loop counter with 3 first, and then add the `rem` afterwards.

Comment: Your question needs more clarity. What is `forloop.counter0` (should that 0 be on the end?) What is rendered when you view source? Assuming your loop works as expected do you know if svg will support`x="n * 3rem"` as its x position (I expect not)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to:
1)interpolate correctly;
2)multiply using `mul` of django-mathfilters; https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/

```
<svg class="wave α-wave">
    {% for i in '0000000000000'|make_list %}
        <rect width="3rem" height="0.5rem" x="{ forloop.counter0 |mul:3 }}rem"></rect>
    {% endfor %}
</svg>
```